# PyroCMS remap gone wrong

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

I have this remap:

```
public function _remap($method, $params = array()) {
        if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
            if ($this -> uri -> segment(1)) {
                $this -> index($this -> uri -> segment(1));
            } else {
                $this -> index();
            }
        } else {
            return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);
        }
    }
```

On my local machine it works fine, but on my test-production it only redirects to index() no matter WHAT I input as querystring. Will someone please help me debug this?

The routes.php is equal on both servers.

If i try to change my index function to only output the requested uri like this:

```
function index($id = null)
{
    $this->output->set_output('id: ' . $id);
    return;
```

only "id : " gets output. Hence the $id is lost somewhere in transition, but I really don't know why

**SOLUTION**
in `system/cms/config/config.php` I had `$config['uri_protocol'] ) 'PATH_INFO'`, but on my production server, this didn't work, so I changed it to `'AUTO'` And it worked.

Comment: Seems that it is a rewrite issue. Have you tried use the same rules in both servers?

Comment: @NomikOS - The routes are the same on both servers, there is a discrepancy in my config file due to the fact that the base_urls are different (one is localhost and other is http://domain)

Comment: Good for you! In any case I said "rules", ie, rewrite rules (possibly in .htaccess). That could cause similar problems when you change servers. Please tell me if the "pretty urls" still works after change to `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'auto'`. Thanks.-

Comment: @NomikOS - if by pretty you mean URI segmented like controller/method/parameter then yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `system/cms/config/config.php` I had `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO'`, but on my production server, this didn't work, so I changed it to `'AUTO'` And it worked.